# Invalid template file in Magento 2.2.7

Tags: template, file

> 1 exception(s):
>       Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'MGS_Mmegamenu::active_menu.phtml' in module:
>   '' block's name: 'active.megamenu.script'

I'm getting this error only on product pages?

Any idea how to resolve this?

layout:

```
/public_html/waverunnerball.com/app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml


<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="active.megamenu.script" template="MGS_Mmegamenu::active_menu.phtml" after="footer-container"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout of product page?

Comment: /app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Comment: We need the content of your layout

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
  <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="active.megamenu.script" template="MGS_Mmegamenu::active_menu.phtml" after="footer-container"/>
  </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: please give your active_menu.phtml file path

Comment: Possible typo? Maybe module is MGS_Megamenu instead of MGS_Mmegamenu

Comment: no, I checked that...

Comment: @RkRathod any idea how to do that?

Comment: please give your active_menu.phtml file path

Comment: please give your active_menu.phtml file path

Comment: I don't have active_menu.phtml file

Comment: active_menu.phtml should be there in app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/view/frontend/templates/active_menu.phtml. If its not there then check the theme files and upload the missing file.